# SubsManager with Iron-Router new API

Tags: meteor, iron-router

any idea how I could connect SubsManager with IR new API?
I use syntax like:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.subscribe('some_subscription').wait();

  if (this.ready()) {
     //something
  } else {
    //something
  }
},{
    name:'1234'
});
```

Tried `subs.subscribe('some_subscription').wait();` but it threw error
`Template never rendered, did you forget to call 'this.next()?`(of course I initialized object `subs`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the subscription manager docs https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager/#limitations

```
 At the moment, the following functionality doesn't work (patches welcome):
.........................

...............
chained .wait() call in Iron Router (issue - you can use waitOn instead)
```

so `subs.subscribe('some_subscription').wait();` this will throw error

From Iron-router docs https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#migrating-from-094

onRun and onBeforeAction hooks now require you to call `this.next()`, and no longer take a pause() argument. So the default behaviour is reversed. For example, if you had:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('login');
    pause();
  }
});
```

You'll need to update it to

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('login');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

Make sure that `this.next()` is called on `onRun` and `onBeforeAction` blocks

and also organize your router code like in `lib/routes.js` file

//configuration

```
 Router.configure({
        layoutTemplate: 'layout',
        loadingTemplate: 'loading',
        notFoundTemplate: 'error'
    });
```

//keep all your routers under a common function

```
Router.map(function() {
     this.route("index",{
           path:"/",
           onBeforeAction:function(){ //do something },
           data:return something,
           onAfterAction
    });
});
```

Finally my answer to the question `any idea how I could connect SubsManager with IR new API?`

```
Router.map(function() {
         this.route("index",{
               path:"/",
               waitOn: function() {
                   return subs.subscribe('some_subscription');
               },
               data:function(){
                    if (this.ready()) {
                         //do something like this.render("loading")
                     } else {
                          //do something this.render("mytemplate")
                     }
               },
               onAfterAction
        });
    });
```

Comment: This is old API and is deprecated in Meteor 1.0, so I tried to avoid it, shame there is no way to do it now. Thanks anyway